# Nested virtualization: VMware Workstation inside Hyper-V

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

Is it possible to use VMware Workstation in Windows 10 Pro or Windows Server 2016 guest inside Hyper-V?
I've heard of Windows Hypervisor platform and Hyper-V integration. But does it apply to Hyper-V guests or only to the Hyper-V host?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do this in a Production environment, but with the newest versions of Hyper-V and VMware, you can do this.

VMware Workstation V16.1 released 11/20/2020.

With prior versions of these apps it was not possible, so this is a bit of a work in progress.

https://www.veeam.com/blog/nested-vitualization-hyperv.html

> From time to time, we need to test something in our infrastructure.
> Production is not good idea for this, so we build a test environment.
> Sometimes, such tests may require changes in the hypervisor, which we
> want to avoid in the production. In such cases, we can work on
> dedicated test hardware or we can virtualize. Virtualization nesting
> can be helpful for development, getting familiar with new
> technologies, new product versions or learning purposes where we can
> easily simulate our production environment. Recently, Microsoft
> released Windows Server 2016 with a lot of cool stuff around
> virtualization like Nano Server, Storage Spaces Direct, Shielded VMs
> and many, many more. If you want to test these new features, you can
> virtualize it.

Comment: OP wants Workstation inside of Hyper-V, not Hyper-V inside of Workstation, which isn't supported/possible and is not what you linked to.  Hyper-V and Workstation can run concurrently on the host, but there is still no support to run Workstation in a nested Hyper-V VM.

Comment: There is some support starting with VMware V16 .  That is, there is some interoperability appearing. Work in Progress .