# Can there be only one? Are Hyper-V, WSL1, WSL2, VMWare Workstation, VirtualBox and TPM Mutually Exclusive?

Tags: windows-10

So back when I last looked at virtualization on Windows, it was pretty easy, you could just install VirtualBox on a computer that had Virtualization enabled, and then start using it...but since then, it's become MUCH MORE COMPLICATED.

Now as far as I can tell there are multiple virtualization programs that can prevent you from using the others.

Off the top of my head there are:

- Microsoft Trusted Platform Management (TPM)

  - This stores your passwords to websites in a hidden VM so that they aren't stolen; sounds like a great idea if you don't want to do any virtualization apart from that.
- WSL1

  - I'm not sure if this uses a VM or not.
- WSL2

  - I believe this uses a VM, but I'm not sure if it's mutually exclusive.
- VirtualBox

  - Cannot be installed if you have Hyper-V or vice versa.
- Hyper-V

  - Cannot be installed if you have VirtualBox installed.
- VMWare Workstation

  - I don't have a copy per-say but since the same virtualization hardware is used I have to wonder if that's the case too.

So, how many of these are mutually exclusive?  All of them?  None of them?  Some of them?

Comment: WSL doesn't use a VM, its a syscall translation. I use virtualbox.. Thats about it heh

Comment: You are best to pick one basic technology and work with that. VMware and Hyper-V are beginning to co-exist but that remains a work in progress.   See: https://superuser.com/questions/1603534/nested-virtualization-vmware-workstation-inside-hyper-v/1603539#1603539

Comment: The current versions of VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation on 20H2 can be installed alongside of Hyper-V; WSL 2 doesn’t require enabling Hyper-V; TPM doesn’t have anything to do with hardware virtualization;

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

Comment: @Ramhound This would result in 12 different questions, I see your point.

Comment: I think a decent answer to your question is that there are two virtualizing technologies that work together at this point - Hyper-V and VMware Workstation. Hyper-V on Windows 10 newest version and VMware Workstation 16.1.  I am using VMware Workstation 16.1 because of its great flexibility (back to Windows 95 and Windows 3.1) and the easy-to-use Network Editor.

Comment: @leeand00 - You have a lot of questions or one giant question, but literally everything you have asked about is documented either by Microsoft, VMWare, or Oracle (VirtualBox).  It really hasn’t change that much, the biggest change, is the ability to keep Hyper-V installed.

Comment: @Ramhound What do you mean by “the ability to keep Hyper-V installed?”

Comment: @leeand00 - Before 20H2 VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation was incompatible with Hyper-V; The current versions of both are now compatible with Hyper-V